# How to set user-level security in 2007+ MS Access?

Tags: security, ms-access, users, access-control

I've read [this MS info](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Set-or-change-Access-2003-user-level-security-in-Access-2010-0c6a10e7-966f-44f4-864e-5d2ef79439fa) which should cover my problem. There are quite clear steps:

> 1. Open the .mdb or .mde file that you want to help protect.
> 2. On the **Database Tools** tab, in the **Administer** group, click the arrow below **Users and Permissions**, and then click **User-Level Security Wizard**.

**The problem:** I don't see *"Users and Permissions"* option in the *"Administer"* group. So I can't proceed. (I use Access 2013, which I don't think that's a problem here.)

In the site, it also says that *"you must also use the `/WRKGP` command-line switch to point to your workgroup information file when you start Access"*.

And I did exactly that (which should be correct according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119986/how-to-use-an-mdw-file-in-access-2010#18131548)):

```
"msaccess.exe" "C:\Temp\testDB.mdb" /wrkgrp "C:\Users\ZygD\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System1.mdw"
```

The file loads, I get no error. Any thoughts? Anything I'm missing?

So, the problem is that I cannot proceed in creating user-level-security. This is a step towards creating separate user accounts for the Access DB file. Initially there is only one Admin account, and it's quite a challenge to create other accounts in new versions of Access...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was stuck in not seeing *"User-Level Security Wizard"*, I made my way to access it by including this item to the custom ribbon tab:

[image]

After that I was able to continue and create users for the DB.